# More info required on form field predefinedlist

Tags: joomla-3.4, form-fields-types

Not much explanation found for the predefinedlist form field at https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

Can someone please help me how this can be configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`predefinedlist` form field is extending ordinary `list` field. It allows to create drop downs with predefined options (as name says). Also allowing to add custom options through XML.

For example it's used by `status`, `userstate` and `useractive` field types (also not documented). These are mainly used by Joomla! Core extensions.

I think that lack of documentation for these fields is caused by extending `list` field. In the end, these fields are ordinary `list` fields.

Take a look at `status` field [source code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/c41fcf023012741e230acac6acbe956f5c275c41/libraries/cms/form/field/status.php).

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Libraries
 * @subpackage  Form
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 */

defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('predefinedlist');

/**
 * Form Field to load a list of states
 *
 * @since  3.2
 */
class JFormFieldStatus extends JFormFieldPredefinedList
{
    /**
     * The form field type.
     *
     * @var    string
     * @since  3.2
     */
    public $type = 'Status';

    /**
     * Available statuses
     *
     * @var  array
     * @since  3.2
     */
    protected $predefinedOptions = array(
        '-2' => 'JTRASHED',
        '0'  => 'JUNPUBLISHED',
        '1'  => 'JPUBLISHED',
        '2'  => 'JARCHIVED',
        '*'  => 'JALL'
    );
}
```

As you can see, it just adds Joomla! Core statuses to protected `$predefinedOptions`.

`JFormFieldPredefinedList` ([source](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/form/fields/predefinedlist.php)) extends `JFormFieldList` ([source](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/form/fields/list.php)) and its only purpose is to add options without adding them through XML. These items are now added to regular `list` field as options.

In custom component it allows to add more options (statuses) if needed, avoiding possibility to remove necessary items. And of course, you can create you own custom field and extend it from `JFormFieldPredefinedList`.

This XML is from Content component (com_content) articles view status filter. As said before, `status` field extends `predefinedlist` field.

```
<field
    name="published"
    type="status"
    label="COM_CONTENT_FILTER_PUBLISHED"
    description="COM_CONTENT_FILTER_PUBLISHED_DESC"
    onchange="this.form.submit();"
    >
    <option value="">JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED</option>
</field>
```

**Result:**

[image]

It adds only one option, which is "- Select Status -" (first default option). All other options are predefined from `JFormFieldStatus` class property `$predefinedOptions`. You couldn't remove or edit them through XML.

Basically, `predefinedlist` form field (`JFormFieldPredefinedList` class) is used to protect some certain options, what field must definitely have. It is not intended to be used as stand-alone field.